# VLC Can't Play UHD Video Shot From my Phone?

Tags: nvidia, video, vlc, gpu

When I try to play video shot from my phone in 4K, the player just stops at one of the first frames.

My Samsung Note 9 Rear Camera shoots in 16:9 UHD at 60FPS and uses the HEVC codec.

When I transfer it to my computer the first few frames play and then the video stream freezes but the track counter keeps going.

Hardware Decoding is set to automatic.
[image: Hardware Decoding]

My hardware specs on my computer are decent, so I would expect to be able to run UHD at 60FPS.

Hardware Specs:

[image: CPU]
[image: GPU]

How can I get VLC to play this type of media?

**EDIT 0:** Text from VLC command line when playing video

```
sarah@LesserArk:~/Camera$ vlc 
VLC media player 3.0.6 Vetinari (revision 3.0.6-0-g5803e85f73)
[000055ac4dfee570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055ac4dff24e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  418.56  Fri Mar 15 12:31:51 CDT 2019 for hardware decoding
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc5b8c0] Failed setup for format vdpau: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: existing hardware acceleration cannot be reused
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc69b80] Could not find ref with POC 28
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcccab80] Could not find ref with POC 34
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcca9ac0] Could not find ref with POC 44
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccebe00] Could not find ref with POC 50
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc993c0] Could not find ref with POC 8
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcccab80] Could not find ref with POC 12
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcca9ac0] Could not find ref with POC 38
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc5b8c0] Could not find ref with POC 4
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc993c0] Could not find ref with POC 18
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccdb4c0] Could not find ref with POC 24
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccba280] Could not find ref with POC 34
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccfc700] Could not find ref with POC 40
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcccab80] Could not find ref with POC 48
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccdb4c0] Could not find ref with POC 2
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccba280] Could not find ref with POC 28
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccdb4c0] Could not find ref with POC 44
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcccab80] Could not find ref with POC 2                                                             
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc5b8c0] Could not find ref with POC 8                                                             
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccebe00] Could not find ref with POC 18                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc993c0] Could not find ref with POC 24                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccfc700] Could not find ref with POC 32                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccdb4c0] Could not find ref with POC 42                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc5b8c0] Could not find ref with POC 46                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccebe00] Could not find ref with POC 12                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccba280] Could not find ref with POC 38
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccdb4c0] Could not find ref with POC 52
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccfc700] Could not find ref with POC 8
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcca9ac0] Could not find ref with POC 14
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc5b8c0] Could not find ref with POC 22
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccebe00] Could not find ref with POC 32
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc69b80] Could not find ref with POC 36
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccfc700] Could not find ref with POC 2
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007fe8fcc33140] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccba280] Could not find ref with POC 24
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcca9ac0] Could not find ref with POC 42
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccebe00] Could not find ref with POC 48
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc5b8c0] Could not find ref with POC 4
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccdb4c0] Could not find ref with POC 12
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccba280] Could not find ref with POC 22
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fccebe00] Could not find ref with POC 26
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcccab80] Could not find ref with POC 52
[hevc @ 0x7fe8fcc993c0] Could not find ref with POC 18
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

**EDIT 1:** After Installing `vdpauinfo`
vdpauinfo was not installed. I installed it, but the video was still laggy. Here was the command line info:

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.6 Vetinari (revision 3.0.6-0-g5803e85f73)
[0000556eff2bc570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000556eff2c04e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  418.56  Fri Mar 15 12:31:51 CDT 2019 for hardware decoding
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c5c100] Failed setup for format vdpau: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: existing hardware acceleration cannot be reused
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cfcf80] Could not find ref with POC 26
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8caa2c0] Could not find ref with POC 32                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c6a340] Could not find ref with POC 42                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8ccb440] Could not find ref with POC 48                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c99bc0] Could not find ref with POC 56                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c5c100] Could not find ref with POC 6                                                             
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8caa2c0] Could not find ref with POC 10                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c6a340] Could not find ref with POC 36                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cec640] Could not find ref with POC 2                                                             
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c5c100] Could not find ref with POC 16                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cbab40] Could not find ref with POC 22                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c99bc0] Could not find ref with POC 32                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cdbd80] Could not find ref with POC 38                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8caa2c0] Could not find ref with POC 46                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c6a340] Could not find ref with POC 56                                                            
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cbab40] Could not find ref with POC 0                                                             
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8c99bc0] Could not find ref with POC 26                                                            
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f5ac8c1cec0] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cdbd80] Could not find ref with POC 0
[hevc @ 0x7f5ac8cfcf80] Could not find ref with POC 22
```

Comment: Do you have the HEVC (x265) support installed?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia How do I check?

Comment: Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Ok, just did, but this didn't appear to help VLC when I restarted it.

Comment: It should included the codec, at least `libx265-165`  (it did in mine) for good measure try reinstalling this same library and also `x265`. And another thing, I see "nvidia" in the tags. Which graphics card do you have and which driver version have you installed?

Comment: Please, try running vlc from terminal, and see if it outputs anything suspicious for playing the file. Adding this output to the post so others could see it may help as well.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I posted the graphics card specs in the post :D I'm using the latest NVIDIA driver, but it doesn't help with the slightly older one either.

Comment: OK, please follow the suggestion above -  run from terminal

Comment: @Hi-Angel Great suggestion! Looks like there were some fireworks on the command line.

Comment: @SarahSzabo ok, it complains about vdapu for whatever reason. Try `sudo apt install vdpauinfo`, then try vlc again in case it fixed the problem *(i.e. in case there some dependency for it to work were missing, which`vdpauinfo` may have pulled)*. If this didn't help, post the output of `vdpauinfo` command.

Comment: Your Gpu doesn't support hevc decoding so it's on your cpu. Depending on the bit-rate and bit-depth of your vids your cpu would be challenged to provide playback of 4k hevc without dropping a lot of frames. 4k AVC would be no problem..

Comment: Maybe try your vids in mpv. If using 18.04 or newer the Ubuntu repo mpv build, whle lacking, is good enough to test. I'd suspect the vid would playback though maybe not smoothly. To get some basic info inc. dropped frames, during playback press `shift+i`

Comment: @doug mpv *does* play it back. It's just at about half the speed. Kinda strange. I wonder how the phone has perfect playback but my computer can't do it. That's kind of crazy.

Comment: Not really. The note 9 has hevc hardware decoding, your laptop hardware doesn't.  hevc is requires more resources to decode, add to that 60 fps vs 30 and likely your laptop screen is 1080p so the vid also has to be scaled to fit. Any recent laptop could decode those vids ok. (- Intel got hevc in broadwell/skylake, nvidia in I believe the 9xx series